# Square Variation Stock status shows none even though there is a valid in stock quantity

Tags: square-connect, square

I'm trying to update the on-hand of a variation using the `inventory/batch-change` API. My system is the source of record for the item on-hand so I'm  posting a `PHYSICAL_COUNT` to the variant. Everything looks fine if you drill down into the stock section of the variant; however, the main item dashboard has a `-` and the variation shows `none` in the stock section. I'm not sure what the issue is because when I post the`PHYSICAL_COUNT` I also set the `state=IN_STOCK`.

#### Here is the json used to update inventory

API URL :`https://connect.squareup.com/v2/inventory/batch-change`

```
{
    "idempotency_key": "XXXXXXXX",
    "changes": [
        {
            "type": "PHYSICAL_COUNT",
            "physical_count": {
                "catalog_object_id": "XXXXXXXX",
                "state": "IN_STOCK",
                "location_id": "XXXXXXXX",
                "quantity": "3",
                "occurred_at": "2020-04-20T15:02:00Z"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ignore_unchanged_counts": true
}
```

[Square Stock None](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVG9g.png)

[Square Stock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xT8OM.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue around this, when using the Inventory API and looking at the dashboard it will be out of sync *unless* you update the item variation in the Catalog API to use individual `location_overrides` (regardless if it's going to be available in every location). This field lives in the `CatalogObject`->`item_variation_data`->`location_overrides` (https://developer.squareup.com/reference/square/catalog-api/upsert-catalog-object#modal__property-item_variation_data).

Comment: Is there an ETA on when this is going to be fixed? Also, I have items where there are `location_overrides` in  `item_variation_data`, but the `stock` statuses still show nothing.